# Remove space at the end of /F

Tags: batch-file, command, dos

Hi there guys I'm trying to use the `FOR /F` command in batch file but I'm getting a problem.

I run it....

```
rem finding model number
for /F "delims= skip=1 tokens=*" %%a in ('wmic csproduct get name') do if not defined model set model=%%a
```

and it works well, I get the result I want

```
result: 637263G
```

Now lets say i create a folder called  "637263G" under c:\windows\

```
eg:c:\windows\637263G\test
```

and i create a batch to go to the path...

```
for /F "skip=1 tokens=*" %%a in ('wmic csproduct get name') do if not defined model set model=%%a

cd windows\%model%\test
```

................................

this bombs out because the %model% is returning  `"c:\windows\637263G \test"` and not `"c:\windows\637263G\test"`

It's leaving a space after the model name.

Does anyone know how to remove the space at the back?

Answer (score 3):

you can suppress all the space in %%a by using substitution :

```
set a=%a: =%
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `set a=%a: =%` for a _normal_ variable, remove the leading `%%`. For a for-parameter the substituion doesn't work

Comment: @jeb thanks for the heads up, you could have edited my answer ;)

Comment: Some computers have spaces in the middle of the value, so this is not a good option.

Answer (score 3):

You should not remove all spaces, as some answers suggest, because some computers have spaces in the middle of the value. See [List of WMIC CSProduct Get Name Results](http://www.faqshop.com/wp/misc/wmi/list-of-wmic-csproduct-get-name-results).

Not only do I get multiple trailing spaces, I also get a trailing carriage return (`<CR>`) that is an artifact of the automatic conversion of WMIC's unicode output into ASCII.

The trailing `<CR>` can be removed by passing the value through another FOR /F loop. This also removes the phantom "blank" line (actually a `<CR>`), so the IF statement is no longer needed.

The trailing spaces can then be removed by using the `~nx` modifier. This works because file names cannot end with space or dot and are automatically removed by the OS. The modifiers normalize the "file name" by removing trailing dots and spaces. This won't work properly if the value contains `\`, `/`, `*`, or `?`, or if it starts with a letter followed by `:`.

```
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%A in (
  'wmic csproduct get name'
) do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set "model=%%~nxB"
```

Another option is to use wmz's suggestion of CSV format, though I still have to remove the trailing `<CR>`.

```
for /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%A in (
  'wmic csproduct get name /format:csv'
) do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set "model=%%B"
```

**EDIT - Why the wmz solution may appear to work, without stripping `<CR>`**

The `<CR>` problem may not be apparent, depending on how you access the `model` variable after it has been set. Normal expansion will strip any `<CR>`, but delayed expansion preserves it.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%A in (
  'wmic csproduct get name /format:csv'
) do set "model=%%A"
echo    Normal expansion strips ^<CR^>:     [%model%]
echo    Delayed expansion preserves ^<CR^>: [!model!]
```

--- OUTPUT ---

```
   Normal expansion strips <CR>:     [LX4710-01]
]  Delayed expansion preserves <CR>: [LX4710-01
```

**EDIT - another way to avoid the `<CR>` problem**

You can use the CSV format and request an extra attribute that appears after the value you want. The `<CR>` will be discarded along with the extra value when you parse out the desired token.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%A in (
  'wmic csproduct get name^,vendor /format:csv'
) do set "model=%%A"
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from trimming return string (as already suggested) you could also reformat wmic output  so it does not return padding (spaces), eg:

`for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%a  in ('wmic csproduct get name /format:csv')`

It's especially handy if you want to return more than 1 column.
*(it will return data as it is, so if it included trailing space, it will be retained. If you want to trim spaces unconditionally, use variable substitution)*

Comment: +1, though I need SKIP=2 instead of 1. I also have an issue with an unwanted `<CR>`.

Comment: @dbenham You're correct about skip, my bad. I copied from  OP and forgot to update. Corrected, thanks! As for `CR`, on my (xp) laptop this problem shows for first (header row, 'name' followed by `CR`), but not value row. Maybe an OS difference.

Comment: I think it is there, but you just may not see it, depending on how you access the variable. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14887005/1012053)

Answer (score 1):

Like Kayasax suggested, you could use variable substitution.
But this only works with *normal* variables, not with %1 nor with for loop parameters.

```
set "model=%model: =%"
```

Or if you are sure that wmic always append one space, you could use also

```
set "model=%model:~0,-1%"
```

This removes only the last character

Comment: Some values have spaces in the middle, so first option is out. My machine has 2 spaces at the end. I don't know if that is constant, so 2nd option could also be problematic. Also, the problem is compounded by the trailing `<CR>` issue.